# PLY Maintaining State Between Requests (Django REST Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, ply

I am using PLY to parse some user input, building up an SQL query as a string which will be returned to the user. The problem I am having is that the parser is maintaining state between requests, so the next user has their SQL query appended to the previous user's.

The state is being stored and updated as follows:

```
import ply.yacc as yacc

class ParserState:
    query = 'ORDER BY '

def p_binary(p):
    ...
    ParserState.query += 'SOME SQL HERE '
```

(Note: this behaviour also occurs even if 'query' is outside of a class)

I have worked around this by being careful to manually reset the string between requests, however I want to figure out how to stop state being maintained between requests?

Comment: Can you show how you are storing the state?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out with some experimentation. The solution was to create a new instance of an object which holds the SQL string in the view which is called, and pass a reference to this object to the parser. ParserState.query was changed to store this reference, and is updated while parsing with the result being returned.

Once the request is completed, the object will be automatically destroyed, thus resetting the state.